# Hebrew TeXLive on Ubuntu 12.04 missing fonts

Tags: fonts, errors, texlive, ubuntu, hebrew

The installation is TeXLive on Ubuntu 12.04.

I've been using a variety of source files, some of them extremely simple.  I can post if necessary, but thought it might be irrelevant given the seeming ubiquity of this error.

It's weird too because I had it working briefly (sort of), by deleting all the `/emph` modified Hebrew text.  Then I kept screwing around with the installation and after that it stopped working again.  What was I doing?  Mostly tlmgr commands to update stuff.  And fc commands like `fc-cache -fv`.  Nothing else can think of.

I've wasted way too much time on this today.  Any pointers or clues greately appreciated.

Anyways here's one source file:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[10pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or.... 

\geometry{top=.75in, right=.5in,bottom=.5in, left=.5in} % for example, change the margins to 2 inches all round
%\geometry{landscape} % set up the page for landscape
 %%%   read geometry.pdf for detailed page layout information
 %%%josh here: i've set these margins up for good 2 or 3 inch marginnotes.  

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{booktabs} % for much better looking tables
\usepackage{array} % for better arrays (eg matrices) in maths
\usepackage{paralist} % very flexible & customisable lists (eg. enumerate/itemize, etc.)
\usepackage{subfig} % make it possible to include more than one captioned figure/table in a single float
% These packages are all incorporated in the memoir class to one degree or another...

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}

%%%  COMMANDS
\newcommand{\hebmy}[1]{\R{#1}}
\newcommand{\heb}[1]{\begin{small}\R{#1}\end{small}}
\newcommand{\hebt}[1]{\begin{scriptsize}\R{#1}\end{scriptsize}}

%%% HEADERS & FOOTERS
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % This should be set AFTER setting up the page geometry
\fancypagestyle{test}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{test}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\scriptsize\today}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}}

\pagestyle{fancy} % options: empty , plain , fancy
\headsep=.75in \textwidth=424pt \textheight=700pt
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % customise the layout...
\lhead{\tiny George Washington \#5 \\ Jerusalem \\ \hebmy{רח ג'ורג' וושינגטון 5} \\ \hebmy{ירושלים} \\ 94187}
\chead{Joshua Cullick \\ \hebmy{יהושוע קוליק}\\ \small joshua.cullick@gmail.com}
\rhead{\tiny Analysis \& \\ \emph{Intelligent} \\ Design}
\lfoot{\tiny \today}\cfoot{ }\rfoot{\tiny \thepage}

%% SECTION TITLE APPEARANCE
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{multicol}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape} % (See the fntguide.pdf for font help)
% (This matches ConTeXt defaults)

%%% ToC (table of contents) APPEARANCE
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} % Put the bibliography in the ToC
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft} % Alter the style of the Table of Contents
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape} % No bold!

%%%josh here, trying to reduce whitespace between sections, below
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
%%% END Article customizations
%%% The "real" document content comes below... 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\date{\today} % Activate to display a given date or no date (if empty),
  % otherwise the current date is printed  
\begin{document}


Hello my name is \hebmy {יהושוע קוליק}


\end{document}
```

This is my BASH log trying to compile:

```
 {LID: command not found
suwylie@wylie-ThinkPad-X61-Tablet:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for wylie: 
root@wylie-ThinkPad-X61-Tablet:/home/wylie# gedit
root@wylie-ThinkPad-X61-Tablet:/home/wylie# updmap-sys --syncwithtrees
Config file: "/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg"
root@wylie-ThinkPad-X61-Tablet:/home/wylie# cd Desktop/
root@wylie-ThinkPad-X61-Tablet:/home/wylie/Desktop# cd texpad/
root@wylie-ThinkPad-X61-Tablet:/home/wylie/Desktop/texpad# pdflatex 20_June_sample.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./20_June_sample.tex
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nyn
orsk, polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbia
nc, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorb
ian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/endnotes/endnotes.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paralist/paralist.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/utf8x.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/rlbabel.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/hebrew.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for
(babel)                the language `Hebrew'
(babel)                I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/english.ldf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/lheenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sectsty/sectsty.sty

LaTeX Warning: Command \underline  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tocbibind/tocbibind.sty

Package tocbibind Note: Using section or other style headings.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tocloft/tocloft.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
No file 20_June_sample.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/lhecmr.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm jerus10
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input jerus10
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2011)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf jerus10
! I can't find file `jerus10'.
 ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input jerus10

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
 ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input jerus10

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: jerus10.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input jerus10' failed to make jerus10.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
 
                   relax 
l.78 ...y name is \hebmy {יהושוע קוליק}
```

I tried using a variety of source files, some of my own that I know had worked from my Window7 / MiKTeX installation, some of which I found online.  The following source file I found online as an example of working with Hebrew in LaTeX:

Source file can be found at [hebexample](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~yoavg/tech-notes/heblatex/hebexample.tex)

for this particular file the BASH log looks like:

```
 root@wylie-ThinkPad-X61-Tablet:/home/wylie/Desktop/texpad# pdflatex hebexample\ \(1\).tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./hebexample (1).tex
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nyn
orsk, polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbia
nc, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorb
ian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/utf8x.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/rlbabel.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/hebrew.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for
(babel)                the language `Hebrew'
(babel)                I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/english.ldf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/lheenc.def)
No file "hebexample (1)".aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/lhecmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm deads10
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input deads10
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2011)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf deads10
! I can't find file `deads10'.
 ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input deads10

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
 ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input deads10

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: deads10.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input deads10' failed to make deads10.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font LHE/cmr/bx/n/14.4=deads10 at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not 
found.
 
                   relax 
l.10 ...�באה מכילה טקסט בעברית}}

? ^C! Interruption.
extract@font ...ont font@name external@font relax 
                                                  font@name relax csname f@e...
l.10 ...�באה מכילה טקסט בעברית}}

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on "hebexample (1).log".
root@wylie-ThinkPad-X61-Tablet:/home/wylie/Desktop/texpad#
```

Comment: What does the `\R` command do or where is it defined (e. g. what package)?

Comment: "To switch to Hebrew inside a left-to-right paragraph, we use the \R macro."
http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/Pubs/eutupon.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the default Ivritex fonts. You can try installing them from http://ivritex.sourceforge.net, but it's considered deprecated.

Preferably, you should install [culmus-latex](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/) which provides a Hebrew support based on the Culmus fonts.

Answer (score 1):

This is a preliminary / draft answer to my own question.  The solution is emerging--I still haven't exploited everything I've learned in the last hour; but...:

- I'm no longer compiling with `pdflatex`; I'm now using `context`.
- [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page) is embedded in TeXLive installation and contains or is associated with LuaTeX components also embedded.
- Both require some [configuration](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Running_Mark_IV) .
- I'm just groping around and found a solution; not enough knowledge for a definitive answer.

The source file looks like this:

```
\definefontfeature[hebrew][arabic][script=hebr]
\definefont[hebrew][name:freesans* hebrew]
\starttext
hello anda gain
\textdir TRT

hello
\hebrew



שלום
סטאנשהחסנטאהשסחנטהאסשנטחהסאשנטוהחסאנטשהחסנטאהשחסנטהאשסוחנטהאסשנטהחסאנטשהחסאנטהשחסנטאהשח
סאטהשוחסנטאהסנטאהשסחנטהאסשנטחהסאנטשהחסאנטשהחסאנטשהחסנטאהשחסנטאהשחסנטאהשחסטנהאשסחנטה

\stoptext
```

Compile (post configuration etc) with `context heb_sample_mod.tex` produces a decent PDF with Hebrew text.  The right margins need some adjustments...

Comment: Not that I doubt that `context` is not a good solution, but: does `LuaTeX` not work with `LaTeX` (i.e., `lualatex`)?  Also, why were you running `latex` as root in your above example?

Comment: Are you fixed to using `pdflatex`? If not, I would recommend using XeLaTeX which has Unicode support and, more interestingly for you, the freedom of choice of fonts with the `fontspec` package. Just set the language(s) with `polyglossia` (the XeLaTeX `babel` equivalent), select any of your system fonts with `fontspec` and you should be good to go (and it is still somewhat LaTeX-y compared to ConTeXt).

Comment: Thanks I'm hung up in Java projects this week.  Last I was in that stuff it was ConText all the way, and it was working.  But I'll keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If one is still forced to use LaTeX with Hebrew `babel`, [see this TSE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76244/12769) for instructions on downloading the missing fonts.

Comment: That's MacOS-specific though; an Ubuntu user would need a pointer to where to put those files